# Queuing ViewControllers to be Pushed One By One

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

How do we "queue" ViewControllers to be pushed one by one?

My app check for number of "Friend Requests" and I would like to push one by one from one to another.

```
 Check for Requests
```

> Found 3 Requests

```
 Push FriendRequestViewController
```

> User Press OK

```
 Push Another FriendRequestViewController
```

> User Press OK

```
 Push Another FriendRequestViewController
```

> Done

I've tried using loop but it would just push three viewcontrollers right away from the currentViewController.

```
for request in friendRequests
{
    let friendRequestViewController = FriendRequestViewController();
    friendRequestViewController.request = request;

   self.navigationController.presentViewController(friendRequestViewController);
}
```

Any idea? Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of something like declaring protocol

```
protocol FriendRequestControllerDelegate {
    func friendRequestContollerConfirmed(friendRequestController : FriendRequestViewController)
}
```

Then, in object that presents friend request

```
//somewhere you have requestsEnumerator
func friendRequestContollerConfirmed(friendRequestController : FriendRequestViewController) {
    request = requestsEnumerator.nextObject();
    if request {
        let friendRequestViewController = FriendRequestViewController();
        friendRequestViewController.request = request;
        friendRequestViewController.delegate = self;

        self.navigationController.presentViewController(friendRequestViewController);
    }
}
```

And where you first present friend request just call this function

In FriendRequestController make itself a target for yours Ok button.

```
func okButtonTapped() {
    if(self.delegate.respondsToSelector:Selector(friendRequestContollerConfirmed)) {
        self.delegate.friendRequestContollerConfirmed(self)
    }
}
```